# How to improve SpaCy matcher pattern

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I use SpaCy tocken matcher to retrieve sentences with a certain structure, for example, "I want a banana".

Now I use pattern like this, based on POS tagging:

```
pattern = [{"POS": "PRON"}, {"POS": "VERB"},{"POS": "NOUN"}]
```

But in this case, SpaCy matcher is only looking for a literal coincidence, and I would like him to look for offers in which these tokens are in the declared order, but not necessarily one after the other. For example, the pattern should find the sentence "I want this banana".

I need a pattern that can match the sentence with the tokens that have the necessary order (as in pattern)but can have other token between.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{"OP": "*"}` to match zero or more tokens of any type.

See all the operators here: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#quantifiers